# i have connected webcam to raspberry pi and now i want to get mpeg stream from webcam to my Laptop ?

Tags: linux, webcam, java

i have used creative webcam and connected to raspberry pi for the purpose to receive mpeg real-time stream from that webcam to my laptop or on android cell-phone but when one of my classmate installed motion software on raspberry pi and connected webcam of creative also he found that this webcam was only sending jpeg stream , so that is why its output was so slow. and when tried to use xuggler to change output data format then i found xuggler not going to work on ARM devices. if any one knows that what should we do means do we buy another webcam which send mpeg stream or there any software which will work here???

Comment: I think you can do it with streamer

Answer (score 1):

You can use my android app "Raspicam Remote" to view a webcam stream from the pi:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pibits.raspberrypiremotecam&hl=en_GB

No extra software required on the Raspberry Pi if you're using the RPi camera and Raspbian OS.

If using a USB webcam, then you will also need to install fswebcam on the pi:

```
sudo apt-get install fswebcam
```

Alternatively you can install mjpegstreamer on the pi, then access the webcam from a web browser on android and pc.
That's a little more complicated as you have to build it from source on the pi:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion imagemagick libjpeg8-dev

svn co https://svn.code.sf.net/p/mjpg-streamer/code/mjpg-streamer/ mjpg-streamer
make

./mjpg_streamer -i "./input_uvc.so -d /dev/video0 -y -f 15" -o "./output_http.so -w ./www"
```